# Cant understand which library it's used

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I wanted to check how the (particles) canvas effect has been generated in this page http://statfa.net/glamorous/kenburn-slider/index.html and I saw the html code. I can see that the part of

```
<div id="canvas" class="bg-overlay" style="background: url(http://statfa.net/glamorous/kenburn-slider/images/pattern-dark.png) repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039);"> ....</div>
```

is dynamic, it changes every 2 seconds, I was wondering why, I checked all the js files but I didn't find any that explains it.

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: if it is the particles effect that you want then look for it online, not in a page... dynamic and moving images are usually a lot of codes and use of externalJS (like JQuery).. and get rid of that code you posed.. it is very misleading... took me forever to get your point

Comment: @Scott is it better know?, I'm sorry about the not clear title

Comment: That is a pretty cool website. Too bad the grammar is off and detracts from the beauty of its presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's using [firefly plugin](https://github.com/motyar/firefly). See the `<script>` tags near the bottom of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/firefly.js"></script>                   
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap-settings.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.kenburnsy.min.js"></script>         
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
```

There are references to `js/firefly.js` and `js/init.js`.
If you check http://statfa.net/glamorous/kenburn-slider/js/init.js, you'll find this syntax

```
$("#preload").delay(1500).fadeOut(1e3,function(){
    animStart();if(firefly){
        $.firefly(
        {color:"#fff",
         minPixel:1,
         maxPixel:3,
         total:35,
         on:"#canvas"}
        )
    }
});
```

which uses `#canvas` that refers to `<div id="canvas">` tag, so I think that explains the canvas effect.